# Isomorphisms in Group theory

Tags: group-theory

Please explain why the groups D6 and Z2 x Z6 are not isomorphic to each other.

I have shown already that A4 and Z12 are not mutually isomorphic (or isomorphic to either of the above groups) but I have difficulty with those.

Comment: One is abelian and the other is not?

Comment: I shouldn't even be allowed on this site for my shortsightedness. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism between two groups preserves the structure of the groups, and one such structural feature preserved by any isomorphism is commutativity.

$D_6$ is *not* abelian (not commutative), whereas $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_6$ *is* an abelian group.

Hence they cannot be isomorphic groups.